# Div position inside img

Tags: image, html, coordinates, drag, resizable

Here is what exactly I am trying to do.

I have an image with square elements inside it. When i click on top left and bottom right corners of those elements they are surrounded with divs with border. I then have functions to drag and resize those divs(once they are created by two clicks). I want to be able to record the resized coordinates of those divs in text boxes.
For example if the image is with height=700 and width=500.
Then if i create a square div inside it with coordinates top left(x=190,y=150) and bottom right(x=290,y=250).
Then if i drag this div around the image i want those coordinates to change accordingly. 
Same thing to happen if i resize it.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Be more brief with code

Comment: Sorry the code is too long for to be written here , and i dont know how to format it to look like code :(

Comment: Imagine i have a #div2 inside an #image. 
And #div2 is draggable. So i want to get the x and y coordinates of #div2 based on the #image width and height.

Comment: here i have added this in a web site.
http://laughter.free.bg/imagemapping/Img1.html

What you need to do is click on top left and bottom right corners of one of the snack packs.
Then you`ll see a box on the right with the coordinates of this Green bordered div.
I want those coordinates to change when i drag or resize this div.
You can see the code in the source of the page

Comment: What's the problem in that...?

Comment: No problem , everything is working , but i dont know what code to use to make the coordinates change accordingly to the moving(resizing) of the divs.

Comment: Yupp i know how you had drawn the div .. i want to know how you are moving the div

Comment: on lines 77 and 78 the code is
$('.kiro'+CountClicks/2).draggable();      
$('.kiro'+CountClicks/2).resizable();

Comment: Currently the coordinates in the boxes on the right are based on the mouse position, and they needs to be based on the divs size once it is created

Comment: Now you want to get the top left co-ordinates and bottom right co-ordinates when you drag or resize it right...??

Comment: Thats right. Those coordinates to be based on the image behind the div. I don't want to get just the size of the resized div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var TopLeftX = $('.kiro'+CountClicks/2).offset().left - $('img').offset().left;
var TopLeftY = $('.kiro'+CountClicks/2).offset().top - $('img').offset().top;
var BottomRightX = TopLeftX + $('.kiro'+CountClicks/2).width();
var BottomRightY = TopLeftY + $('.kiro'+CountClicks/2).height();
```

Comment: i think we are nearly there. 
When i alert BottomRightX and BottomRightY i get (NaN). 
I have replaced "document.getElementById" with "$".
Any suggestions? :S

Comment: What about TopLeftX and TopLeftY...??

Comment: You mean all are NaN ...??

Comment: var TopLeftX = $('.kiro'+CountClicks/2).offsetLeft - $('img').offsetLeft;
var TopLeftY = $('.kiro'+CountClicks/2).offsetTop - $('img').offsetTop;
var BottomRightX = TopLeftX + $('.kiro'+CountClicks/2).offsetWidth;
var BottomRightY = TopLeftY + $('.kiro'+CountClicks/2).offsetHeight;

Comment: It is all sorted now.
Thanks a lot for your time.

var xDiff = $('img').offset().left - $('.kiro1').offset().left; 
var yDiff = $('img').offset().top - $('.kiro1').offset().top;